# "with" argument in scale() in R

Tags: r, arguments

I'm trying to understand how to do clusters in R. I'm following [this](http://blog.hackerearth.com/practical-guide-to-clustering-algorithms-evaluation-in-r) blog post, but I don't understand the argument `with` in his code.

```
head(water_data)
         V1    V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7   V8  V9  V10 V11 V12 V13  V14 V15  V16 V17 V18 V19
1: D-1/3/90 44101 1.5 7.8 182 407 166 66.3 4.5 2110 7.9 197 228 70.2 5.5 2120 7.9 119 280
2: D-2/3/90 39024 3.0 7.7 182 443 214 69.2 6.5 2660 7.7 197 244 75.4 7.7 2570 7.6 119 474
3: D-4/3/90 32229 5.0 7.6 182 528 186 69.9 3.4 1666 7.7 197 220 72.7 4.5 1594 7.7 119 272
4: D-5/3/90 35023 3.5 7.9 205 588 192 65.6 4.5 2430 7.8 236 268 73.1 8.5 2280 7.8 158 376
5: D-6/3/90 36924 1.5 8.0 242 496 176 64.8 4.0 2110 7.9 197 236 57.6 4.5 2020 7.8 119 372
6: D-7/3/90 38572 3.0 7.8 202 372 186 68.8 4.5 1644 7.8 197 248 66.1 8.5 1762 7.7 150 460
   V20  V21 V22  V23 V24 V25 V26 V27  V28  V29  V30  V31  V32  V33  V34  V35  V36  V37  V38
1:  94 72.3 0.3 2010 7.3  18  84  21 81.0 0.02 2000 39.6 58.8 95.5 85.4 70.0 90.2 79.4 87.3
2:  96 79.2 0.4 2700 7.5  18  91  17 94.1 0.00 2590 39.6 60.7 94.8 85.4 80.8 90.2 79.5 92.1
3:  92 78.3 0.2 1742 7.6  18 128  21 81.0 0.05 1888 39.6 58.2 95.6 85.4 52.9 90.2 75.8 88.7
4:  96 77.1 0.4 2060 7.6  20 104  20 96.7 0.00 1840 33.1 64.2 95.3 87.3 72.3 90.2 82.3 89.6
5:  88 68.2 0.2 2250 7.6  19 108  22 65.9 0.02 2120 39.6 62.7 95.6 85.4 71.0 92.1 78.2 87.5
6: 100 76.0 0.3 1768 7.5  20 100  28 82.1 0.00 1764 39.6 59.7 96.5 86.7 78.3 90.1 73.1 84.9
     V39
1:  99.6
2: 100.0
3:  98.5
4: 100.0
5:  99.5
6: 100.0
```

He uses when scaling the data using `scale()`.

```
#scale the variables
scaled_wd <- scale(water_data[,-c("V1"),with=F])
```

I tried `?scale` but can't find anything about this argument.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

`with` is not an argument to `scale`. It is an argument regarding the `data.table` object being used to store the data in question. Specifically, `with` is used to allow you to use quoted names to select columns in a data table. `data.table` is an additional package on top of base R, and does things that you cannot do with regular data frames. I suggest checking out the [cheat sheet](https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/img/blog/data+table+cheat+sheet.pdf) linked here.